# Automatic evaluation of a function for variable values defined from different data tables in the attachments

Tags: functions, evaluation, data, autocomplete, table

I want to evaluate a function whose variable values are defined in different data files. I want to know that how can I write code such that when the function's evaluation is exhausted for one table, then it should automatically start for the next table and so on. Here is an example:

```
fn[x_, y_] := Sin[x] y^3
```

The {x, y} values are defined in the tables:

```
dt1 = {{1, 1.1}, {2, 1.2}, {3, 1.3}, {4, 1.4}, {5, 1.5}, {6, 1.6}, {7,
     1.7}, {8, 1.8}, {9, 1.9}, {10, 1.10}} 
dt2 = {{1, 2.1}, {2, 2.2}, {3, 2.3}, {4, 2.4}, {5, 2.5}, {6, 2.6}, {7,
     2.7}, {8, 2.8}, {9, 2.9}, {10, 2.10}};
dt3 = {{1, 3.1}, {2, 3.2}, {3, 3.3}, {4, 3.4}, {5, 3.5}, {6, 3.6}, {7,
     3.7}, {8, 3.8}, {9, 3.9}, {10, 3.10}};

Evaluate[fn[x_, y_]] at dt1,dt2,dt3 ?
```

I am not sure how to include this data in three separate data file making ".dat" files, that's why I copied it here.

Now the question is:
how to evaluate fn[x_, y_] for "dt1", "dt2", "dt3" in one single code WITHOUT defining/repeating the same code three times for each data. Also, I want to call the data from the ".dat" files, not in the above the format. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `fn @@@ # & /@ {dt1, dt2, dt3}` ??

Comment: `Map[Apply[fn], {dt1, dt2, dt3}, {2}]`

Comment: @Syed&cvgmt "Also, I want to call the data from the ".dat" files, not in the above the format."

Comment: @SciJewel It is implicit, and should be obvious, that you need to import the data from the dat files first. Look at `Import`, then assign the imported values to dt1, dt2, dt3, and then u se either of the approaches suggested above. If that's not what you mean, then you need to explain the problem better.

Comment: @MarcoB: Okay, then is there any way to import 10 files of data in .txt format located all in a single folder with a single "Import" command? Thanks!

Comment: @SciJewel Something like `Import[#, "TXT"]& /@ FileNames["*.txt"]` perhaps?

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks. But where to insert the "File Path" in this line? For example, my "File Path" to the data is "C:\\Users\\abc\\dt"  where "dt" is the folder containing all the .txt files. I don't know where to insert this path in the code you wrote?

Comment: @SciJewel You can add the path right in the `FileNames` call (e.g. `FileNames["C:\\Users\\abc\\dt\\*.txt"]`), or you can construct a path programmatically using `FileNameJoin`, e.g. `FileNames@ FileNameJoin[{"C:\\Users\\abc\\dt", "*.txt"}]`.

Comment: @MarcoB:I get the following error message:                                                           During evaluation of In[174]:= Import::noelem: The Import element "TXT" is not present when importing as Text.

During evaluation of In[174]:= General::stop: Further output of Import::noelem will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[174]= {$Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed, \

Comment: @SciJewel Try "Text" as the format specification instead of "TXT": `Import[#, "Text"]&`

Comment: @MarcoB: Works fairly good, Now how to suppress the non-numerical headings of the columns in the .txt files? And how to choose the specific two columns out of several given in the text file. For example, each text file includes col1   col2  col3  (Ist row)  11  22   33 (2nd row) .  All text files include this format and I want to only pick the numbers which starts from the 2nd row. And I want only col1 and col3, skipping col2. Thanks!

Comment: @SciJewel Use `Part` on the output of `Import`, eg `Import[...][[2;;, {1, 3}]]`

Comment: @MarcoB: Where to use "Part". When I write the following code, Import[#, "Text"] & /@ 
 FileNames["C:\\Users\\dt\\*.txt"][[3 ;;, {1, 3}]], it gives the error message, Part specification {C:\\Users\\dt\\}: Import::chtype: First argument 3;;All is not a valid file, directory, or URL specification.

Comment: @SciJewel But I showed you! Right after `Import`. Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the language a bit more on your own at this point.

Comment: @MarcoB: Sure thanks. When I put "Part" ([[2;;,{1,3}]]) at the output of "Import", I get the error message as copied in my last comment. Although, your suggestion works for this example ({{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, 
   a6}}[[2 ;;, {1, 3}]]), where the table is defined inside the notebook, but not imported. I guess the problem is in the .txt file. May be, "Part" does not work on txt file?

Comment: @MarcoB: It is not conformed that "Part" only works for .dat files but not for .txt files. I have manually converted tens of .txt files to .dat format and then applied the "Part" in the exactly the same way as you suggested and it works now. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!